# Wire Up events with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling

I am working on to implement HTML 5 file uploading. My application uses JQuery. I've been using this page [Reading local files in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) for reference, but I've hit a roadblock. I need to kick off an event when the "change" event is fired. However, I can't figure out how to wire it up with JQuery. The following code doesn't show an error in the console, however, it also doesn't display an alert message. Because of this, I know my wireup isn't happening. What am I doing wrong?

```
<input id="uploadInput" type="file" multiple="multiple" />

$().ready(function () {
  $("#uploadInput").bind("change", beginUpload);
});

function beginUpload(e) {
  alert("Here");
  var fileCount = e.target.files;
  alert("Uploading " + fileCount + " files...");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Works in chrome 16 too : http://jsfiddle.net/MjMAe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What am I doing wrong?"

Possibly it should be:

```
$(document).ready(handler);
```

rather than $().ready as apparently that isn't recommended. You should put some alerts inside the ready function to see if it's being called at all.

But also you're spending time writing code which is already available for free?

There is a jquery plugin for supporting file drag'n'drop with HTML 5 available at https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop

Comment: Or possibly this syntax was what was intended, i.e., passing a callback function to $():
$(function() { $("#uploadInput").bind("change", beginUpload); });